# Identify source cause for Cordova no launching in iOs 9 but works fine in iOs 10

Tags: ios, cordova

As title said, I'm facing issue with Cordova working properly in iOs 10 both on simulator and device, but not launching on iOs9 (no deviceready fired, no script started at all.
It just display the index.html static content file. Xcode does not tell me anything in the console.

I'm using latest version of Cordova, and also all plugins are up to date.
I tried to deactivate each plugin one by one, but nothing happen, I'm blind with the cause of the issue.

Here is my config file, in case anyone could have a immediate root cause I missed here:

Any other advices for debug approach is welcome!

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.my-domain.myapp" version="2.0.3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>revolution</name>
    <description> My Description </description>
    <author email="my_email" href="my_website"> Author detail </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <access origin="cdvfile://*" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="data:*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <icon height="29" src="res/ios/icon-29.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="40" src="res/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="res/ios/icon-40-2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="50" src="res/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="57" src="res/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="58" src="res/ios/icon-58.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="114" src="res/ios/icon-57@2x-114.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="116" src="res/ios/icon-58@2x-116.png" width="116" />
        <icon height="120" src="res/ios/icon-60@2x-120.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="res/ios/icon-76@3x-180.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="60" src="res/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="res/ios/icon-60-2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="72" src="res/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="res/ios/icon-72@2x-144.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="res/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="87" src="res/ios/icon-29@3x-87.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="152" src="res/ios/icon-76@2x-152.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="100" src="res/ios/icon-50@2x-100.png" width="100" />
        <splash height="480" src="res/screen/ios/launch_iPh4x3-480.png" width="320" />
        <splash height="960" src="res/screen/ios/launch_iPh4x3@2x-960.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1136" src="res/screen/ios/launch_iPh5-1136.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="res/screen/ios/launch_iPh6-1334.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="res/screen/ios/launch_iPh6p-2208.png" width="1242" />
    </platform>
    <engine name="browser" spec="~4.1.0" />
    <engine name="ios" spec="~4.3.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="~2.3.1">
        <variable name="CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value=" " />
        <variable name="PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value=" " />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" spec="~1.6.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="~4.3.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-google-analytics" spec="~1.7.4" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="~1.3.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-badge" spec="~0.7.4" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="~1.1.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="~1.3.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="~2.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~4.0.0" />
    <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner" spec="~6.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="~1.0.4" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" spec="~1.3.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-sqlite-storage" spec="~1.5.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-googlemaps" spec="~1.4.0">
        <variable name="API_KEY_FOR_IOS" value="my_google_key" />
        <variable name="NSLOCATIONWHENINUSEUSAGEDESCRIPTION" value="Show your location on the map" />
        <variable name="NSLOCATIONALWAYSUSAGEDESCRIPTION" value="Trace your location on the map" />
    </plugin>
</widget>
```

Comment: Were you able to find the cause of the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking your iOS crash logs:

`~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/<DEVICE_NAME>`

or

Xcode > Window > Organizer > Devices tab > Device Log

Shortcut to Organizer window is cmd-shift-2.